# how to create silent installer exe for wpf c# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, deployment, installation

I developed C# wpf application using 3rd party SDK now i want to deploy application. i want to create exe which is download and install application directly from web with minimal user interaction.

i also want to install .net framework silently on client machine without user interaction. for example like zoom meeting windows application.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried ClickOnce?

Comment: yes,i tried click once learn from you tube videos but i'm not satisfied yet. can you suggest me proper way.

Answer (score 0):

you say download and install but how?

- if you want to install like [msi setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx) i'm suggest you to try [squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)
  which is like clickonce but it works.
- But you can also check: [Installshield](https://www.flexera.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/) or [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) which it can let you create an update windows service. With windows service privileges, you can do your job without user interaction.
- Also the other way which i prefered 2 months ago is your own application. You can create an updater windows service application. I've developed an updater software which checks an url for the version, if the version higher then download and update the application. Also check if application is running if app is not running then run it. i'm starting processes with an 3rd party tool which you can find it [here](https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser) you will need it if you want to develop your own application which is windows service. Because of windows service [isolated "session 0"](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086228-what-is-session-0-isolation-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-it-)

I think best way will be your own development.

Comment: yes, i also tried advance installer and successfully deployed my app (in both way .exe and .msi) but i want to build exe some thing like this, can you please download app setup from https://www.eztalks.com/ (windows app from footer section) and install so,you get more clear idea